# ping output sporadically missing (labeled as wrong unit) in journal of systemd service

Tags: systemd, ping, systemd-journald, systemd-unit

I am using `ping` in a script, which runs in a systemd service unit. The output from ping is sometimes (often) missing in the unit's journal. I.e., it is missing from `journalctl --user -u MyUnit`.

Note that I can observe this regardless of whether the script is a long-running script that calls `ping` in its own loop (variant 1), or I'm using a timer to periodically start it (variant 2). Note that I'm also recording timestamps in an extra file to verify that the script actually ran. This is indeed always the case.

---

**Variant 1**

Script:

```
$ cat ~/ping_test
#!/bin/bash
ITERATION=0
while true
do
    echo "Iteration $ITERATION"
    let ITERATION=ITERATION+1
    date >> timestamps
    ping -c 1 vodafone.de
    sleep 10
done
```

Service unit:

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/ping_test.service
[Unit]
Description=Ping Test
    
[Service]
ExecStart=%h/ping_test
    
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

---

**Variant 2**

Script:

```
$ cat ~/myscript
#!/bin/bash
echo HELLO
date >> timestamps
ping -c 1 vodafone.de
```

Service unit:

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/test.service
[Unit]
description = test

[Service]
ExecStart=%h/myscript

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Timer unit:

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/test.timer
[Unit]
Description = myscript

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:*:0/10
AccuracySec=1s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

---

Below is output from Variant 2, but Variant 1 effectively has the exact same problem.

The following shows that the output from `ping` is sometimes missing from the unit's journal, even though other output is visible. Look at the consecutive `HELLO` messages without any `PING` output in between.

```
$ journalctl --user -n 40 --no-pager -u test
Dec 20 16:16:20 debian myscript[2839]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Dec 20 16:16:20 debian myscript[2839]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.241/21.241/21.241/0.000 ms
Dec 20 16:16:30 debian systemd[1686]: Started test.service.
Dec 20 16:16:30 debian myscript[2842]: HELLO
Dec 20 16:16:40 debian systemd[1686]: Started test.service.
Dec 20 16:16:40 debian myscript[2845]: HELLO
Dec 20 16:16:50 debian systemd[1686]: Started test.service.
Dec 20 16:16:50 debian myscript[2849]: HELLO
Dec 20 16:16:50 debian myscript[2850]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Dec 20 16:16:50 debian myscript[2850]: 64 bytes from hilfe.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=20.6 ms
Dec 20 16:16:50 debian myscript[2850]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Dec 20 16:16:50 debian myscript[2850]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Dec 20 16:16:50 debian myscript[2850]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.591/20.591/20.591/0.000 ms
Dec 20 16:17:00 debian systemd[1686]: Started test.service.
Dec 20 16:17:00 debian myscript[2852]: HELLO
Dec 20 16:17:00 debian myscript[2853]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Dec 20 16:17:00 debian myscript[2853]: 64 bytes from incubator.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=17.7 ms
Dec 20 16:17:00 debian myscript[2853]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Dec 20 16:17:00 debian myscript[2853]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Dec 20 16:17:00 debian myscript[2853]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.718/17.718/17.718/0.000 ms
Dec 20 16:17:10 debian systemd[1686]: Started test.service.
Dec 20 16:17:10 debian myscript[2862]: HELLO
Dec 20 16:17:20 debian systemd[1686]: Started test.service.
Dec 20 16:17:20 debian myscript[2865]: HELLO
Dec 20 16:17:30 debian systemd[1686]: Started test.service.
Dec 20 16:17:30 debian myscript[2869]: HELLO
Dec 20 16:17:30 debian myscript[2870]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Dec 20 16:17:30 debian myscript[2870]: 64 bytes from hilfe.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=20.3 ms
Dec 20 16:17:30 debian myscript[2870]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Dec 20 16:17:30 debian myscript[2870]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Dec 20 16:17:30 debian myscript[2870]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.328/20.328/20.328/0.000 ms
Dec 20 16:17:40 debian systemd[1686]: Started test.service.
Dec 20 16:17:40 debian myscript[2872]: HELLO
Dec 20 16:17:40 debian myscript[2873]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Dec 20 16:17:40 debian myscript[2873]: 64 bytes from incubator.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=22.9 ms
Dec 20 16:17:40 debian myscript[2873]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Dec 20 16:17:40 debian myscript[2873]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Dec 20 16:17:40 debian myscript[2873]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.900/22.900/22.900/0.000 ms
Dec 20 16:17:50 debian systemd[1686]: Started test.service.
Dec 20 16:17:50 debian myscript[2877]: HELLO
```

The following shows that the output from `ping` is not lost, but is in fact visible, but the unit is sometimes incorrect. Note that the `PING` output is sometimes under unit `myscript` (wrong), and sometimes under `user@1000.service/test.service` (correct).

```
$ journalctl --user -n 40 --no-pager --output=with-unit
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:10 UTC debian myscript[3065]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:10 UTC debian myscript[3065]: 64 bytes from hilfe.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=19.0 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:10 UTC debian myscript[3065]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:10 UTC debian myscript[3065]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:10 UTC debian myscript[3065]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.019/19.019/19.019/0.000 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:20 UTC debian user@1000.service/init.scope[1686]: Started test.service.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:20 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3067]: HELLO
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:20 UTC debian myscript[3068]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:20 UTC debian myscript[3068]: 64 bytes from hilfe.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=18.8 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:20 UTC debian myscript[3068]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:20 UTC debian myscript[3068]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:20 UTC debian myscript[3068]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.815/18.815/18.815/0.000 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:30 UTC debian user@1000.service/init.scope[1686]: Started test.service.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:30 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3070]: HELLO
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:30 UTC debian myscript[3071]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:30 UTC debian myscript[3071]: 64 bytes from incubator.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=17.8 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:30 UTC debian myscript[3071]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:30 UTC debian myscript[3071]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:30 UTC debian myscript[3071]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.773/17.773/17.773/0.000 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:40 UTC debian user@1000.service/init.scope[1686]: Started test.service.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:40 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3073]: HELLO
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:40 UTC debian myscript[3074]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:40 UTC debian myscript[3074]: 64 bytes from incubator.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=19.3 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:40 UTC debian myscript[3074]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:40 UTC debian myscript[3074]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:40 UTC debian myscript[3074]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.251/19.251/19.251/0.000 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:50 UTC debian user@1000.service/init.scope[1686]: Started test.service.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:50 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3077]: HELLO
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:50 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3078]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:50 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3078]: 64 bytes from incubator.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=20.9 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:50 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3078]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:50 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3078]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:20:50 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3078]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.893/20.893/20.893/0.000 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:21:00 UTC debian user@1000.service/init.scope[1686]: Started test.service.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:21:00 UTC debian user@1000.service/test.service[3080]: HELLO
Wed 2023-12-20 16:21:00 UTC debian myscript[3081]: PING vodafone.de (139.7.147.49) 56(84) bytes of data.
Wed 2023-12-20 16:21:00 UTC debian myscript[3081]: 64 bytes from hilfe.vodafone.de (139.7.147.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=20.0 ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:21:00 UTC debian myscript[3081]: --- vodafone.de ping statistics ---
Wed 2023-12-20 16:21:00 UTC debian myscript[3081]: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
Wed 2023-12-20 16:21:00 UTC debian myscript[3081]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.992/19.992/19.992/0.000 ms
```

Also, `/var/log/syslog` (via `rsyslog`) also contains *all* messages.

At this point I believe this to be a bug in systemd. To me it looks like the service unit is *sometimes* not "inherited" properly by the started process, and therefore the journal doesn't capture the output unit properly.

Observed on an untouched Debian 12 Live (standard) instance running in a VM, and Raspberry Pi OS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that then !

Create a timer unit that runs ping every 10 second.

```
/etc/systemd/system/ping.timer
[Unit]
Description=Runping every ten seconds

[Timer]
OnBootSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

And the service file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/ping.service
[Unit]
Description=pinger
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ping -c 1 vodafone.de
```

daemon-reload and enable the ping timer ..then use journalctl -u ping.service to see all its activity.

Comment: That doesn't explain the observed behavior. Aside from the fact that this isn't a user unit, and the timer isn't correct as written (it is not periodic, as there's either an `OnUnit[In]Active` or `OnCalendar` missing), this seems to make it worse. The timer only runs about once every minute now. // Weirdly: If I *spam* the system with `systemctl --user status ...` every second via ssh, the time is spot-on. If I leave the system idle for half a minute or so, then it starts running less frequently. I'm beginning to think systemd tries to enter a power saving state or something due to inactivity.

Comment: It will run in monotonic time which is what you want most of the time...starting ten seconds after boot..

Comment: `OnBootSec=10s` alone just runs it once, 10 seconds after boot. It is not periodic by itself without `OnUnitActiveSec` or `OnUnitInactiveSec`. **But**, that is completely besides the point of the original question, which is *why* is the output missing.